# How do I make a functor out of an arbitrary function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, functor

I have a bunch of functions which I want to use as functors (that is, use types instead of pass pointers to the functions, or any other kind of data).

Is there an elegant/idiomatic/standard way of doing this with the standard library, or the standard library + Boost? Perhaps using `bind()` somehow?

Or should I go with something simplistic (well, kind of simplistic) such as:

```
template<typename Function, Function& F, typename... Parameters>
struct functor {
    using function_type            = Function;
    using parameters_as_tuple_type = std::tuple<Parameters...>;

    auto operator() (Parameters&&... params) ->
        decltype(F(std::forward<Parameters>(params)...))
    {
        return F(std::forward<Parameters>(params)...);
    }
};
```

**Notes:**

- C++11 solutions are preferred, but if you have something requiring even C++17, that's also interesting.
- My "solution" might not work, I think, for overloaded functions.

Comment: What's the motivation for this? Have you found a use case where a `std::function` doesn't do the job?

Comment: @RSahu: Don't `std::function`s have data members?

Comment: Why would you use `std::function` if you don't need all of its features? It's not the right tool of the job unless you need type erasure and ownership semantics.

Comment: @einpoklum, it sure does. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target.

Comment: @RSahu: So I can't use it. I need a type with no data members.

Comment: Re: "My solution might not work for overloaded functions". No solution works for overloaded functions (yet). We don't really have a way to refer to a group of otherwise identical functions by just the name. Therefore you always need to be specific about the exact function you want to wrap (in the case of overloads casting to the appropriate type to match the overload you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a concrete example for a fixed type.

```
int foo( int );
void foo( double );

struct foo_t {
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const
  ->decltype( foo( std::declval<Args>()... ) )
  {  return ( foo( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) ); }
};
```

now `foo_t` is an object that invokes the overloads of `foo` via perfect forwarding.

To make it generic:

```
#define RETURNS(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOAD_SET_TYPE(...) \
  struct { \
    template<class...Args> \
    auto operator()(Args&&...args)const \
    RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) ) \
  }
```

so we can do

```
using foo_t = OVERLOAD_SET_TYPE(foo);
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28fb62903722f15c).

You cannot manipulate overload sets of a function as an object; the only way to do it is textually.  Hence the macro.

This has all of the usual imperfections of perfect forwarding.  There is no way to generically avoid those imperfections.

Answer (score 4):

If the function is not overloaded, you can do this in C++17:

```
template <auto F>
auto to_function_object()
{
    return [](auto&&... xs) -> decltype(auto)
    { 
        return F(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...);
    };
}
```

```
void a(int) { }

int main()
{
    auto af = to_function_object<a>();
    af(1);
}
```

---

If the function is overloaded, there's no way to pass its *overload set* as an argument to another function or a template. You're forced to manually write a wrapper lambda on the spot. Example:

```
void foo(int)  { }
void foo(char) { }
// ...   
bar([](auto x){ return foo(x); });
```

[N3617](https://wg21.link/n3617) aimed to solve this issue by introducing a *"lift" operator*.

[P0119](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0119r0.pdf) by A. Sutton solves the problem in a different way by allowing overload sets to basically generate the "wrapper lambda" for you when passed as arguments.

Until any of those proposal is accepted you can use a *beautiful* C++14 macro instead:

```
#define LIFT(f) \
    [](auto&&... xs) noexcept(noexcept(f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...))) \
        -> decltype(f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...)) \
    { \
        return f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); \
    }
```

Comment: How can your construct differentiate between the overloads of `a`?

Comment: @einpoklum: it can't unless you explicitly specify the overload you're interested in. In the second part of my post I show some proposals that wanted to solve this issue. Unfortunately you have to use a macro today (or spell out the lambda).

Comment: Do you mean "spell out its *type*"?

Comment: @Quentin: I expressed myself quite poorly - is it clear after my edit?

Comment: Oh, alright. I was thinking about `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(foo)`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: (1) The Macro is just C++14, isn't it? (2) Can you rephrase your answer so as to produce a _type_ rather than a value? Something I can in my declarations rather than inside blocks of code?

Comment: @einpoklum: (1) Yes, it is. - (2) The `functor` solution in your question is then basically what you want - it is equivalent to my `to_function_object` if you replace `typename Function, Function& F` with `auto F`. Alternatively you could always `decltype(to_function_object<foo>())`.

Comment: So, +1, but I'll want to accept something which sticks to C++11 (since I want to use this with CUDA).

Comment: @einpoklum failing to mention CUDA requirement is a pretty big thing to skip over.  And you explicitly asked for [tag:c++1z] in your question.  Don't move the goalposts; if you have a question about solving this problem in pure C++11 CUDA-compatible code, ask a different question.

Comment: @Yakk: I didn't want to limit my question to just CUDA - as I'm not the only person who might be reading this question. And I did say C++14/17 answers are interesting, but not what I prefer. And I did + 1 this answer. So I think I'm within the bounds of fairness...